# Join rows based on common columns 1 table in SQL Presto

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I'm using Amazon Athena and I have one large dataset. There is data that I want to join within the same table that comes up in different columns but they have the same ID and Account Name. Example below:

```
Sub_ID   Account Name                Contract_Length         Cost

1         Canary                        3 years
2         Mockjay                       3 years
3         Pidgeon                       2 years
1         Canary                                             50.45
2         Mockjay                                            96.5
3         Pidgeon                                            112.21
```

What I want it to look like:

```
 Sub_ID     Account Name                Contract_Length         Cost

    1         Canary                        3 years           50.45
    2         Mockjay                       3 years           96.5
    3         Pidgeon                       2 years           112.21
```

How would I do this in SQL Presto within 1 table and 2 common columns (ID and Account Name)?

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
select sub_id, account_name, max(contract_length), max(cost)
from t
group by sub_id, account_name;
```

That said, you can probably fix the code that generates the result set in your question.  When this occurs, it is usually due to a malformed aggregation query.

Comment: this didn't combine the data, it just gave me blanks on the cost column

Comment: @shaheed313 . . . If that is the case, then the `sub_id` and/or `account_name` values might *look* the same but they are not the same.